# Rocket Software SQL ODBC, Retrieve Wrong Filenames

Tags: u2

I installed Rocket Software for accessing an Unidata Db through SQL Server 2008. The idea is to write SQL Procedures for populating SQL Tables,  but the problem I am getting is retrieving wrong filenames i. e.  Select * from MyDb_Members. I got the field names as Member{Name,  Phone{number. In my unidata core these fields are named as Member Name, Phone Number. 
Do you know if there is way to run sql queries with those field names without getting sql query errors.  It looks sql server does not like to use that name convention:
Select Member{Name from MyDb_Members
Error near '{' 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try formatting the query using NATIVE keyword. I don't use Unidata, but in UniVerse this works well. I have a lot of columns that contain periods and those are illegal column names in standard SQL.

```
{ NATIVE "Select * from MyDb_Members" }
```